# Get Position in Original String from `StringTokenizer`

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I need to get the space-separated tokens in a string, but I also need to know the character position within the original string at which each token *starts*. Is there any way to do this with `StringTokenizer`. Also, as I understand it, this is a legacy class; is there a better alternative to using `StringTokenizer`.

Comment: Most would use `String#split(...)` instead of StringTokenizer. I think that the API even states this. **Edit:** and in fact the API does state this: `"StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead. "`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should always use `String#split()` to split your string rather than `StringTokenizer`.

However, since you also want the position of the tokens in your string, then it would be better to use [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class. You have got [`Matcher#start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start%28%29) method which gives the position of the string matching the pattern.

Here's an example: -

```
String str = "abc asf basdfasf asf";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\S+").matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.start() + ":" + matcher.group());
}
```

The pattern `\\S+` matches the non-space characters from that string. Using [`Matcher#find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) methods returns all the matched substring.

Comment: I picked this answer because it also handles cases where there may be multiple spaces in between words.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this yourself using `String.split()`

```
 String text = "hello world example";
 int tokenStartIndex = 0;
 for (String token : text.split(" ")) {      
   System.out.println("token: " + token + ", tokenStartIndex: " + tokenStartIndex);
   tokenStartIndex += token.length() + 1; // +1 because of whitespace
 }
```

this prints:

```
token: hello, tokenStartIndex: 0
token: world, tokenStartIndex: 6
token: example, tokenStartIndex: 12
```

Comment: What if there are two subsequent spaces in the String?

Answer (score 0):

I improved micha's answer, so that it can handle neighboring spaces:

```
String text = "hello  world     example";
int start = 0;
for (String token : text.split("[\u00A0 \n]")) {
    if (token.length() > 0) {
        start = text.indexOf(token, start);
        System.out.println("token: " + token + ", start at: " + start);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
token: hello, start at: 0
token: world, start at: 7
token: example, start at: 17
```

Comment: what if there are multiple tokens with the same value? indexof will incorrectly give the index of the first occurrence.

Comment: @Paul No. That's why there is `indexOf` with two arguments. Did you try it at least?